# Google Earth in real time

Tags: google-earth

I would like to ask if I can see Earth in real time? And how?
Can I see Google Earth few weeks ago?

Comment: Google Earth and Google Earth Engine are not the same.

Answer (score 1):

You... could look out of your window? But I guess you're asking whether there's something like a webcam for real time Earth observation. There kind of are, e.g. weather satellites, but those have a [ground resolution of 1 x 1 km](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GOES-16#:%7E:text=bands.%5B36%5D-,ABI%20spectral%20bands,-hide) - probably not what you're looking for. You could buy some [TerraSAR-X](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TerraSAR-X) images, but those wont be available for every day and are very costly.

What you're probably after are those [high resolution images](https://www.google.de/maps/@51.5009584,-0.1235785,61m/data=!3m1!1e3?entry=ttu) Google Earth provides where you can spot cars and even single people - those are actually images taken from an airplane, not a satellite.

Earth observation in general is complex, costly and still limited by the capabilities of our sensors (aka cameras) and data transfer rates.

If you really want to dig into it, maybe start [here](https://business.esa.int/newcomers-earth-observation-guide#) - if you're trying to spy on your neighbours, just don't - if you're trying to pass time, "normal" Google Earth will have to do - and if you're trying to document local changes in landscape or building, maybe create the data yourself using a drone (while heeding the corresponding laws).